# Why additional plans are created under simple parameterization?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, plan-cache, simple-parameterization

I have a table which has 2163 rows and clustered index on id column.

I run the following queries:

```
select id
from ticket_attach
where id = 1

select id
from ticket_attach
where id = 2

select id
from ticket_attach
where id = 3
```

Here is my plan cache:

[image]

Well, when I execute 1st query, I result in creating both adhoc plan and prepared plan.

I thought that under **simple parameterization**, the next two queries where **id=2** and **id=3** will use only prepared plan. Yes, those queries really used prepared plan, BUT in addition to that, they created adhoc plans. **I wonder why SQL Server created those plans if it used already prepared plan**. What it the purpose of creating them and taking place of plan cache?

Comment: The ad-hoc plans are just a pointer to the prepared plan, not a full execution plan. View the plan XML using `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`.

Comment: so, we can neglect sizes of those pointers as they do not cause inflating of plan cache?

Comment: The `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.size_in_bytes` column will show the memory consumed of the Adhoc entries, which are much smaller than the prepared plan and facilitate efficient cache lookups. Note that if you turn on the 'optimize for ad hoc workloads' option, you'll get an even smaller Compiled Plan Stub that serves a similar purpose.

Comment: I have checked sizes for all adhocs and it turned out they have the same size. The question which comes into my mind is what is then the purpose of simple parameterization if my plan cache will be filling anyway with those adhocs meaning that new plans are created? I am aware of 'optimize for ad hoc workloads' but I do not want to touch it for now

Comment: Right now I re-checked"SQL Server Query Performance" written by Grant Fritchey where he explains in more detail how simple parameterization works but even there he does not explain why additional plans occur.

Comment: Compare the AdHoc size to the Prepared plan. I would expect the AdHoc plans to be smaller but all the same size since they just point to the Prepared cache entry.

Comment: Yes, prepared plan is twice bigger than adhoc plan size. I think now it makes sense. Thank you